# Spring Kafka - In Memory Grouping Consumer Timeout Mechanism

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Hello Gary and the Spring Kafka community! :)

I have a Kafka consumer in which I'm accumulating/grouping messages. I've used Spring's scheduling mechanism to spin up a thread and produce a 'timeout message' to the topic that my grouping consumer is consuming from. This way if/when a message isn't receive for some time, we aren't relying on the invocation of the listener method to see if we've timed out.

Since then, we've done some work to enable us to reliably scale horizontally. Now there is no guarantee that the timeout message is received by the consumer that published it. I'm thinking about maybe grabbing the assigned partitions by having a `ConsumerAwareRebalanceListener` that sets them in some static variable somewhere. Then, I'll just publish to one of the partitions the listener is assigned to.

Wondering if there is better way?

Using Spring Boot 2.7.8 w/ Spring for Apache Kafka v2.8.11.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container can be configured to publish container idle events if no records are received during the `idleInterval`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#events

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#idle-containers

> While efficient, one problem with asynchronous consumers is detecting when they are idle. You might want to take some action if no messages arrive for some period of time.

> You can configure the listener container to publish a ListenerContainerIdleEvent when some time passes with no message delivery. While the container is idle, an event is published every idleEventInterval milliseconds.

Comment: My grouping listener is stateful, in that I'm accumulating messages in memory. The current 'timeout message' I'm publishing makes it so that the same thread doing the consuming/grouping is the thread handling the timeout. Can this be achieved with the `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`?

Comment: By default, the `ListenerContainerIdleEvent`event listener is called on the same thread that calls the listener.